# Python DataFrame Create new column with matching rows

Tags: python, dataframe

In my dataframe I have multiple column DateTime taht I want transform in only one column. But on the same row the datetime can not have the same value.

```
DateTime-equip1-TEMP    equip1-TEMP DateTime-equip1-DO  equip1-DO   
    0                      a            1               test    
    1                      b            2               test1   
    2                      c            3               test2
```

This is what I want to realize:

```
DateTime    equip1-TEMP     equip1-DO
    0           a           NaN         
    1           b           test    
    2           c           test1   
    3           NaN         test2
```

The DateTime must match the value in other columns and add new rows if needed. I find multiple post to add a column but I don't find anyone with this problem and I don't find a solution from my side.. Thanks for your help. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that, there may be a more elegant way but it works.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date_time1": [0, 1, 2], "equip1": ["a", "b", "c"], "date_time2": [1,2,3], "equip2": ["test", "test1", "test2"]})

result = pd.merge(df[["date_time1", "equip1"]],df[["date_time2", "equip2"]], left_on="date_time1", right_on="date_time2", how="outer")
result["date_time"] =result["date_time1"].fillna(result["date_time2"]) 
result = result[["date_time", "equip1", "equip2"]]
```

Output:

```
    date_time   equip1  equip2
0   0.0            a    NaN
1   1.0            b    test
2   2.0            c    test1
3   3.0          NaN    test2
```